# How to adjust the repeat interval and duration for delay effect in Ableton Live?

Tags: effects, ableton-live, delay

I remember in Cubase the audio delay effect had parameters where you could dictate how often a delay repeated, and for what duration..
Is there a way of adjusting these parameters in Ableton?

Ideally I want an audio sample to for example repeat every crotchet and with each repeated sample decaying after x number of miliseconds or whatever..

Any help much appreciated

cheers,

Rowan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Ableton you have following parameters on every Delay Plug-In: Simple Delay, Ping Pong Delay, Filter Delay and Granular Delay.

The time between the synced Repeats is determined by the Numbers in the Yellow Boxes (Lower numbers -> faster delay). By the Number with the % you can let the Delay groove by offsetting it from the synced Repeat. By pressing the sync button you can unsync the delay from bpm and type a value in ms.

The Feedback determines how long/often the delay is repeated (every repeat drops in some dB). So there is no possibility to say - i want exactly 5 repeats. But with a workaround -> Gate after the delay you can cut off everything after 5 repeats.

The parameter Dry/wet determines how much dry signal and how much delay you get. (if you use delay on a send return channel 100% wet makes sense)

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Simple Delay effect that comes with Ableton, I believe the only way to adjust the timing is by selecting one of the boxed numbers for each side of the stereo field. For the number of repeats/decay, adjust the feedback knob.